# Google Play optimization feature suggests English(US) to English(UK) translation

Tags: android, localization, google-play

With the new Google Play optimization suggestions, one of the suggestions it gives me is:

```
Your app is popular with users who speak English (United Kingdom) but your APK is not translated yet.
```

Similarly for the store listing

```
Your app is popular with users who speak English (United Kingdom) but this app's store listing isn't translated yet.
```

This seems like a bit of a ridiculous optimization. I think people generally accept UK or US spelling regardless of their own preference.

Is there an easy way to get my app to think it's English (UK) rather than English (US)? Similarly, is there an easy way to transfer all my current text (and images) to English (UK) on the Play Store without just copy-pasting every field and re-uploading my images?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html):

> you could create a small file called res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml that includes only the strings that should be different when the application runs in the U.K.

Comment: I'm new to android.So, I may be asking a silly question.. I have added description in both English US and UK in Play Store. Now it's asking me to upload apk. Can I upload the same apk used for UK in US as there's no difference in strings. Do I need to add new folders inside the values directory even if there's no difference.